# GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 6: Could not resolve host

Tags: ubuntu, curl, libcurl, vagrant-windows

I'm facing the issue in my site. I have spent 2 days on that but no luck.

## Error in DB Logs

> GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 6: Could not resolve
> host: www-dev.drupalsite.com (see
> http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html ) in
> GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::createRejection() (line 186 of
> /var/www/html/site-d8/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php
> ).

## Error while accessing site

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Note that this is local dev-site using **vagrant on ubuntu (VM Virtual Box)**

Comment: seems like you have a dns issue. are you able to to resolv something, for example "dig stackoverflow.com" ?

Comment: @manu-eidenberger, yes it is resolving. I tried with "dig stackoverflow.com"....
Its giving me a response like.... (this isn't full response)
`;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 64972
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 7

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;stackoverflow.com.             IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
stackoverflow.com.      220     IN      A       151.101.1.69`

Comment: vagrant@localhost ~ $ host stackoverflow.com
stackoverflow.com has address 151.101.1.69
stackoverflow.com has address 151.101.193.69
stackoverflow.com has address 151.101.65.69
stackoverflow.com has address 151.101.129.69
stackoverflow.com mail is handled by 5 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
stackoverflow.com mail is handled by 5 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
stackoverflow.com mail is handled by 1 aspmx.l.google.com.
stackoverflow.com mail is handled by 10 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
stackoverflow.com mail is handled by 10 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.

Comment: can you try following php code : `var_dump(gethostbyname('www-dev.drupalsite.com'));`

Comment: @ManuEidenberger, thanks.... I have done it, see my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I have resolved that issue by adding hostname in Ubuntu **/etc/hosts** file.